# expose firestore uuid in url

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a website using React and Firestore. I'm currently loading a details page using react routing like this.

```
<Link to={`/details/${obj.id}`} state={{ obj: obj }}>
```

Which works fine and creates a URL like this.
http://localhost:3000/details/4T9joNCN8KxgABC123 etc.

This ensures that there are no duplicate details pages, but is there any risk in exposing the firestore UUID like this?
Should I use obj.title and add a random uuid or something similar?

Comment: Is the `UUID` generated using the `add()` function? Or is the `UUID` the UID that comes from the authentication mechanism?

Comment: the UUID is coming from addDoc()